# How does pytorch.autograd.Function calculate dL_dy?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

This code calculate grad of y=x**2.

In this code, dL_dy is  [0., 2., 8.]  How do they calculate dL_dy? Where did this tensor came from ?

```
import torch 
from torch.autograd import Function
class Square(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx,input):
        ctx.save_for_backward (input)
        return torch.square(input)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx,dL_dy):
        print('dL_dy',dL_dy)
        print('ctx.saved_tensors',ctx.saved_tensors)
        x, = ctx.saved_tensors
        return dL_dy * 2 * x
    
    
square = Square.apply 
x = torch.arange(3).to(torch.float64).requires_grad_(True)
y = square(x)
L = torch.sum(y*y)
L.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say your `f(y) = x**2`, so `f'(y) = 2*x`

`x = torch.arange(3).to(torch.float64).requires_grad_(True)` means `x=[0,1,2]`, we can compute `y = x**2 = [0,1,4]`.

So when you call `L.backward()`, it will apply `f'(y)` (calculating the gradient of `y`), and stored in `dL_dy`.

That's why `dL_dy = f'(y) = 2 * [0,1,4] = [0,2,8]`